# Traspasar abecedario a una Columna de tabla

Tags: java, android, string

Buenas

El problema es sencillo pero aun no logro dar con la via correcta para empezar a programar ya que no tengo mucho tiempo en dedicarme a programar.
La pregunta es la siguiente...

Como puedo generar un array de abecedario para insertarlo en las columnas de mi tabla, el codigo donde se ingresa los parametros es el siguiente.

```
//GENERA LAS COLUMNAS DE LA TABLA
private List<ColumnHeaderModel> getColumnHeaderList() {
    List<ColumnHeaderModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN_SIZE; i++) {
        String strTitle = "A";

        ColumnHeaderModel header = new ColumnHeaderModel(String.valueOf(i), strTitle);
        list.add(header);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Aqui el bucle gira y va imprimiendo la palabra con el numero que va pasando hasta que llega al limite de Columnas

Mi idea es que cada conteo imprima la letra en la columna correspondiente empezando con A = 0 hasta la Z = 25

Habrá algun metodo mejor para hacer esto?

Si lo resuelvo lo publicaré

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Ignacio_aa, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** , saludos!.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando el código ascii para ello. Luego conviertes el carácter ascii a String.

> "A" = 65; "a" = 97
>
> "Z" = 90; "z" = 122

El código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
//GENERA LAS COLUMNAS DE LA TABLA
private List<ColumnHeaderModel> getColumnHeaderList() {
    List<ColumnHeaderModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN_SIZE; i++) {
        // En minúscula a-z
        //String strTitle = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(i + 97)); 
        // En mayúscula A-Z
        String strTitle = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(i + 65));
        ColumnHeaderModel header = new ColumnHeaderModel(String.valueOf(i), strTitle);
        list.add(header);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Sin embargo puede darse el caso en el que siga, y exceda de los 25 caracteres (a-z). Por lo cual convendría colocar un tope para que continúe el ciclo.

```
//GENERA LAS COLUMNAS DE LA TABLA
private List<ColumnHeaderModel> getColumnHeaderList() {
    List<ColumnHeaderModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // En caso de que se exceda de los 25 caracteres.
    int restart = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < COLUMN_SIZE; i++) {
        // Simplemente para que tenga un tope
        restart = (i / 25) * 25;
        // En minúscula a-z
        //String strTitle = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(i + 97 - restart)); 
        // En mayúscula A-Z
        String strTitle = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(i + 65 - restart));
        ColumnHeaderModel header = new ColumnHeaderModel(String.valueOf(i), strTitle);
        list.add(header);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Lo que desea el OP es "imprima la letra en la columna correspondiente empezando con A = 0 hasta la Z = 25"

Answer (score -2):

De una forma sencilla puedes crear un array de los elementos que conforman el abecedario y mostrarlos de acuerdo a su indice:

```
 String[] Abecedario = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

        for (int i = 0; i < Abecedario.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Columna: " + i + " valor :" + Abecedario[i]);

        }
```